# APPNAME is not included in QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation

Tags: c++, linux, qt

My app is called `unwallpaper` and I would like to get its app data path:

```
qDebug() << QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
```

This return `/home/sign/.local/share` on Linux but what should be returned is `/home/sign/.local/share/<APPNAME>`, according to [Qt Document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum)

Should I set APPNAME value somewhere? I am using Qt Creator with qmake. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [application name docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop):

> If not set, the application name defaults to the executable name (since 5.0).

It's strange that the returned path didn't contain the `<APPNAME>` at all.

So a better approach is to explicitly set the [application name](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop) and/or [organization name](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#organizationName-prop) like this:

```
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("unwallpaper");
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("organization");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationFilePath). It returns the file path of the application executable (including executable file name).

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and investigated it. The general possible reason is because you call QStandartPaths before QApplication initialization. It could be if you call QStandartPaths inside global or static methods. Generally, be careful with globals and statics initialization because it performed before main {} starts.
Wrong example:

```
/* includes etc */


class A
{
public:
    
    A();
    
//.....

}


class B

{
public:

    B() {};

//.....

private:

    static A* a;

}


B::a = new A();
/* A::A prints path(s) without AppName because at the moment of
initialisation main not started yet and AppName not assigned */


main
{
    QApplication ap(argc, argv); 
    ap.setApplicationName("AppName");
    ap.setApplicationDisplayName("AppDisplayName");


    new B();

}

void A::A()
{
    qDebug() << QStandardPaths::AppConfigLocation; 
}
```

Correct example:

```
    /* includes etc */
    
    class A
    {
    public:
        
        A();
        
    //.....
    
    }

    class B
    
    {
    public:
    
        B();
    
    //.....
    
    private:
    
        static A* a;
    }

    B::a = nullptr;
    
    main
    {
        QApplication ap(argc, argv); 
        ap.setApplicationName("AppName");
        ap.setApplicationDisplayName("AppDisplayName");
    
        new B();
    
    }
    
    void A::A()
    {
        qDebug() << QStandardPaths::AppConfigLocation; 
    }
    
    void B::B()
    {
        if (a == nullptr) a = new A();
    /* A::A prints correct path(s) because all constructors invoked after QApplication initialization.
       if protects static a from re-initialization on multiple B creation */
    
    }
```